# Convert nested match expression to function

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have some nested Discriminated Unions

```
type Job = Sniff | Guard
type Dog = Chihuahua | GermanShepherd of Job
```

Here's a function that takes a `Dog` and returns a `string`.

```
let dogPrinter d =
    match d with
    | Chihuahua -> ""
    | GermanShepherd g ->
        match g with
        | Sniff -> ""
        | Guard -> ""
```

I can convert the first `match` to the `function` syntax:

```
let dogPrinter = function
    | Chihuahua -> ""
    | GermanShepherd g ->
        match g with
        | Sniff -> ""
        | Guard -> ""
```

How can I convert the second `match` to `function`?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). _Why_ do you want to do this? It's perfectly readable as-is. You could use nested patterns to avoid the second match though.

Comment: Why? Just wondering how. What do you mean by nested patterns? Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way of avoiding nested matches in scenarios like this is to use nested patterns:

```
let dogPrinter = function
    | Chihuahua -> ""
    | GermanShepherd Sniff -> ""
    | GermanShepherd Guard -> ""
```

You can nest patterns as deeply as you need, just like you can nest expressions when creating the values.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of, which I think might generally be the best approach, because it separates the concerns appropriately. However, I don't think this `function` keyword adds any value. I usually just stick with the `match` keyword.

```
let jobPrinter = function
  | Sniff -> ""
  | Guard -> ""

let dogPrinter = function
  | Chihuahua -> ""
  | GermanShepherd job -> job |> jobPrinter
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I think @glennsl answer is what you should consider doing here's an aswer to what OP asked for:

```
type Job = Sniff | Guard
type Dog = Chihuahua | GermanShepherd of Job

let dogPrinter = function
    | Chihuahua -> "Voff"
    | GermanShepherd g ->
      g |> (  function 
              | Sniff -> "Sniff"
              | Guard -> "Guard"
            )
```